# How to create mysql users using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I wnat to create mysql user accounts from a php code. my code is working but can't login to user accounts which create using that code. this is my php code

```
//include database connection function
include("dbcon.inc.php");

//prepare db connection
dbcon(1,"root");

//call db_user function to create new db user account
db_user(1,1,"insert","user123");

function db_user($user_admin,$user_active,$user_action,$user_name){
    global $conn;
    $sql_query="";
    $host_name="localhost";
    $staff_password="123";
    $database_name="smart_lib";

    if($user_action=="insert"){
        //create user account
        $sql_query="CREATE USER '$user_name'@'$host_name' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS '$staff_password';";
    }
    elseif($user_action=="update"){
        //update
        $sql_query="REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM '$user_name'@'$host_name';";
    }

    //if user is active give privilages
    if($user_active==1){
        //if user is an admin give admin privilages
        if($user_admin==1){
            $sql_query.="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$user_name'@'$host_name' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;";
        }
        //if user not an admin give privilages without grant optin
        else{
            $sql_query.="GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `$database_name`.* TO '$user_name'@'$host_name'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";
        }
    }
    $sql = $conn->prepare($sql_query);
    $sql->execute();

    echo $sql_query."<br/>";
}
```

I get the query using `echo $sql_query` and execute it on php myadmin. it worked correctly.

This is my database connection.

```
function dbcon($user_type,$user_name){
    $Database = "smart_lib";
    $Hostname = "localhost";
    $Username = $user_name;
    $Password = "123";

    try{
        global $conn;
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$Hostname;dbname=$Database", $Username,$Password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->exec ("SET NAMES utf8");
    }
    catch(PDOException $exp)
    {
        echo "Error! ".$exp->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: Have you thought that maybe it's your login code that doesn't work?

Comment: Code is working. no errors. but can't login to created users.

Comment: Then like @Fred said... It's not working lol.. It doesn't always error if it doesn't work you know.

Answer (score 1):

These are correct **sql statements** - tested:

```
// Build another variable: 
$user = $user_name . '@' . $host_name;

// Sql statements:

$sql_query = "CREATE USER `" . $user . "` IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS '" . $staff_password . "';";

$sql_query = "REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM `" . $user . "`;";

$sql_query .= "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `" . $user . "` REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;";

$sql_query .= "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `" . $database_name . "`.* TO `" . $user . "`; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";
```

**Notes:**

The problem resided - at least in my tests - in this representation of the user name: `'$user_name'@'$host_name'`. My personal tests showed this:

[image: User created]

- If you use `'abc'@'def'`, then the user `abc` and the host `def` is created.
- But if you use `abc@def` with backticks around, or `'abc@def'`, then the user `abc@def` is created, with the host `%`.

In general, use backticks when you pass special characters like "@".

I also recommend you to use exception handling on `prepare()` and `execute()` as well.

When you're using prepared statements then you should bind the input parameters, not pass them directly to the sql statements. For this task use the `bindValue()` or the `bindParam()` function.

And don't use `global` connection variable, but create a connection on the page which requires it and pass it as argument to each function.

Maybe this will be helpful:

[Complete example of PDO w. prepared statements and exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264986/php-pdo-skips-some-queries-from-executing/45271106#45271106) (see especially "generalFunctions.php").

On development (not on production!) use error reporting and display:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Good luck!